# Finding the mean of a Maxwell Distribution

Tags: statistics

Let the velocity of gas particles be modeled by the Maxwell distribution. The probability density function is

$$ f(v) = 4\pi \cdot\left( \frac{m}{2\pi K T} \right) ^ {\frac{3}{2}}v^2\cdot e^{-v^2(m/[2KT])}$$

I found that the mean is $2a \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ where $a=\sqrt{\frac{kT}{m}}$ from Wikipedia.

Could you please explain how is the mean obtained?

Comment: A source indicates that this is equivalent to a chi distribution with df = 3. But I only understand chi-square and beta distributions. Is there a way to transform the Maxwell distribution to another type of distribution?

Comment: is $v$ the random variable?

Comment: @kolonel Yes, $v$ is the random variable. Sorry - I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given the hand-written solution of the problem.  Let me know if it is legible and clear

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I went over your solution twice and got it finally (:

Comment: You are welcome!